# Capture image from webcam with JavaScript without page refresh

Tags: javascript, html

I created HTML form and one of the fields is a `canvas` div which takes image from user's webcam and save it as base64_encode, and currently just `console.log()` the data.
the problem is after each time user press the "take picture" button, the page refresh and all the data that was filled in earlier inputs disappear/get's deleted. 
I've been trying to under stand what causes this refresh but can't figure it out...

This is the relevant HTML part:

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <input minlength=8 type="password" class="form-control" name="pass" placeholder="Enter Password" required/>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <div id="camera">
        <div class="center clear">
            <video id="video" width="320" height="240" autoplay></video>
            <button id="snap">Take Picture</button>
            <canvas id="canvas" width="320" height="240"></canvas>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and the JS:

```
  // Put event listeners into place
  window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    // Grab elements, create settings, etc.
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
      context = canvas.getContext("2d"),
      video = document.getElementById("video"),
      videoObj = { "video": true },
      errBack = function(error) {
        console.log("Video capture error: ", error.code);
      };

    // Put video listeners into place
    if(navigator.getUserMedia) { // Standard
      navigator.getUserMedia(videoObj, function(stream) {
        video.src = stream;
        video.play();
      }, errBack);
    } else if(navigator.webkitGetUserMedia) { // WebKit-prefixed
      navigator.webkitGetUserMedia(videoObj, function(stream){
        video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
        video.play();
      }, errBack);
    } else if(navigator.mozGetUserMedia) { // WebKit-prefixed
      navigator.mozGetUserMedia(videoObj, function(stream){
        video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
        video.play();
      }, errBack);
    }

    // Trigger photo take
    document.getElementById("snap").addEventListener("click", function() {
      context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 320, 240);
            var image = document.getElementById("canvas");
            var pngUrl = canvas.toDataURL();
            console.log(pngUrl);
    });
  }, false);
```

any idea why clicking `<button id="snap">Take Picture</button>`
 refresh's the page and how can i prevent it?? thx

Comment: Is your button inside of a form?

Comment: yes....ill upload a bigger part of the html

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `<button>` inside of a `<form>` then clicking it will submit the form by default. To prevent this, you can use [`event.preventDefault`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) to stop the submission.

```
var form = document.querySelector('form');
form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
}, true);
```

Comment: it didnt work but guided me to the solution...thanks

Answer (score 0):

In-case someone else will get caught in the issue, i managed to solve this one using the guidance of @Mike C...
i simply add this to the `button`:

`<button id="snap" onclick="return false;">Take Picture</button>`